# What is the method for calculating rotations - in particular this tetrahedron example?

Tags: 3d, three.js

I'm having difficult understanding rotations of irregular objects such as triangles and tetrahedron's.  I'm trying to rotate a tetrahedron so that two corners will be straight along the x axis and it will sit flat on the ground.  Below is what I have so far - close, it is on the ground but how do I move the left corner down (see arrow in image) so it is in line with the right corner?

[image]

This is what's flattening the tetrahedron:

```
tetrahedron.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, -1 ).normalize(), Math.atan( Math.sqrt(2)) ) );
```

Took me an age to understand that `Math.atan( Math.sqrt(2))` was 54.735610317245346 degrees.  Do I need to apply a new `makeRotationAxis` or simply rotate it?  In general what is the method for calculating rotations like this?

Comment: A 4×4 transformation matrix is an affine transformation, meaning it carries not only rotations, but also translation, scaling and shearing. From all the available operations, the statement does only a rotation. So what is the question now?

Comment: "how do I move the left corner down (see arrow in image) so it is in line with the right corner?" "Do I need to apply a new makeRotationAxis or simply rotate it? In general what is the method for calculating rotations like this?"

Comment: This combination worked 

`//flatten the tetrahedron on the ground
tetrahedron.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, -1 ).normalize(), de2ra(54.735610317245346) ) );

//fix the rotation
tetrahedron.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ).normalize(), de2ra(15) ) );

//fix the offset
tetrahedron.position.set( -141.4, 0, -81.8 );`


and I understand what it's doing but getting 15 degrees and the x and z offsets were trial and error.  How should they be calculated precisely?